# rDNS mx record problem, smtp test fails

Tags: smtp, domain-name-system, mx-record, reverse-dns

down vote favorite

I am doing test at mxtoolbox.com

ptr: ip -> mydomain.com
mx: mydomain.com ->myip

but smtp:173.231.15.144 -> OK - myip resolves to myip.hosted.static.hostingfirm.com / Warning - Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner

at my dns, i have for mydomain forward zone
(same as parent folder) Host(A) myip
(same as parent folder) Mail Exchanger(MX) on [10]mydomain.com.

and for reverse lookup
myip Pointer(PTR) mydomain.com.

what am I missing then at stmp test, reverse dns fails?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't run your reverse DNS lookup, your hosting company does, unless they use rDNS forwarding, which is unlikely. So you have three options:

1. Ignore the warning. Although it helps that your SMTP banner matches your forward and/or reverse DNS, it isn't usually necessary.
2. Get your hosting company to change your rDNS record to be the same as your SMTP banner.
3. Change your MX record and SMTP banner to the same as the rDNS record.

Comment: as a developer, it is not easy to set up these server things. reverse dns settings well done. i realized that i should use hosting firm dns records as i did for network adapter, i should do the same mailenable dns settings. issue solved. thanks for answer